# ImageMagick, an explanation of `import -snaps -pause`?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

For the background story my goal is to use `import` and `convert` commands from ImageMagick to take screenshots with the `-snaps -pause` option and make a Gif animation with `convert`. In an other word I want to make a desktop recorder using ImageMagick in a Bash script. Since my question is about the specific use of `import -snaps -pause` I don't covert the conversion stage.

So far the following commands line work great for this purpose:

`import -window root -snaps 30 -pause 1 -monitor screenshot.miff`

In the cmd line example above I set up `-snaps 30` so it will take 30 images with 1 second delay between each other `-pause 1`. That make more or less a 30sec Gif animation.

So now I want to improve the fluidity ( images/second ) of my animation and find a way to setup a desired im/s snapshots rate. I currently trying to get a 2 images/second animation with the following:

`import -window root -snaps 30 -pause 0.5 -monitor screenshot.miff`

I was thinking the `-pause 0.5` will wait 0.5 sec before each snapshots and make a 15 sec Gif animation with a 2 images/second rate but it actually make the opposite, look like a 1 second Gif animation with 30 images/second.

Can an ImageMagick wizard explain how `-snaps -pause` can be correctly use or share good documentation or examples on this subject please ?

ImageMagick 6.9.2-7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the amount of time each frame appears in the resulting GIF like this:

```
import -window root -snaps 30 -pause 0.5 -monitor -set delay 50 screenshot.gif
```

Comment: That's the thing actually, I setup the delay in the conversion stage, what I am looking for is a way to setup the -pause option below 1 second, not scaling the frame rate in an existent Gif. I try your example but it's make no difference.

Comment: If I run `time import -window root -pause 1 ...` it takes 40 seconds to run, whereas if I use `-pause 0.5` it takes 20 seconds to run so it does seem to be honouring the fractional number of seconds in `-pause`, on my system at least.

Comment: Thanks for the `time` cmd it's actually very useful tricks, that's strange because I test with `-snaps 30 -pause 1` that's make a 33.902 second duration but with `-snaps 30 -pause 0.5` that's make a 3.601 second duration. I run [Qubes-os](https://www.qubes-os.org/) but I don't see any reasons that's will change the way ImageMagick tools work.

Comment: Normally I use macOS and tested with that, but I just ran it on Linux Mint and saw the same as you. If you remove the `-pause` altogether and make the output file `grab-%04d.gif` you will get all the grabs as fast as it can go. Then you could delete 7 of every 8 frames or somesuch in a script to get the rate you want then use `convert -delay 50 grab-*gif result.gif` to assemble the remaining frames into a GIF.

Comment: I will dig on this and update if I found my way out, many thanks for your time.